# Chrome extension, pageAction not hidden

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have created a page action that I want shown on a specific path of a domain. At some point if this path contains the string `/search/` I want the action hidden. The is the code that should achieve that:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        'active' : true,
        'lastFocusedWindow' : true
    }, function(tabs) {
        var url = tabs[0].url;
        if (url.indexOf('/search/') !== -1){
            chrome.pageAction.hide(tabs[0].id)
        }
    });
...
```

The condition is executed and the `tabs[0].id` has the id of the tab but the page action is not hidden (the button I have does not get grey and upon clicking it it shows the popup when it should not.

Is there something I am misunderstanding about pageActions in Chrome? How can I conditionally hide the action?